# Another "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" on Form Submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, http-headers

I receive the following error, when I submit text to a single-field form to my node.js server:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:264:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\routes\index.js:15:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\routes\index.js:11:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\hbhar\Desktop\Basic WebApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
```

Although the router successfully renders the page after a form is submitted, I can't send any data or log data to the console. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve the issue based on answers to similar questions. Thank you in advance. Also, any resource suggestion for HTTP headers (other than MDN), is also appreciated.

My index.js file (found in /routes):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Welcome Page
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome'));

// After Form Submission
router.get('/submitform', function(req, res, next) 
  {
    res.render('submitform');
    next(); 
  }, function(req,res)
  {
    const formsubmission = req.query; 
    res.send(formsubmission);
    console.log(formsubmission);
  }
 );

module.exports = router;
```

The file used to run npm (usually called app.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const webapp = express();
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

webapp.use(expressLayouts);
webapp.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Body Parser Middleware
webapp.use(express.json());
webapp.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 

// Routing to default directory
webapp.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
// Link folder for static files
webapp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
webapp.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calling both `res.render('submitform');` and `res.send(formsubmission);` for the same request. You can only make **one** response to a request. Pick one of those.

Comment: Thanks! I thought adding another function would circumvent this issue. Is there any alternative to send the query to a new page? Or should I just have it return to the original page (that would work for me in this case)?

Comment: You need to return a single page with everything you want to return included in it.